# Error with CVS server on Ubuntu

Tags: cvs

I have a dedicated Ubuntu 8.04 server that I would like to set up a CVS repository on.  I have followed various guides to try to set this up and always get stuck at the same point.

```
$ cvs -d :pserver:pcm@localhost:/cvsrepo checkout .
cvs [checkout aborted]: could not get working directory: Function not implemented
```

I have set up the server two different ways, one using cvs and xinetd to run the server, and currently I am trying the cvs/cvsd method.  Both ways I am able to start the server and log into the server using a local account or a cvs created account.  Once I try to check out or import anything I get the error.

In my current attempt I am not using a local account, but a cvsd generated username/password.

I am on CVS version 1.12.13.

Here is the trace:

```
$ cvs -t -d :pserver:pcm@localhost:/cvsrepo checkout .
-> main: Session ID is cZozIZVrlXzLEMLt
-> main loop with CVSROOT=/cvsrepo
-> safe_location( where=(null) )
-> open_connection_to_server (:pserver:pcm@localhost:/cvsrepo)
-> Connecting to localhost(127.0.0.1):2401.
cvs checkout: warning: unrecognized response `S -> serve_directory (.)' 
from cvs server
cvs checkout: warning: unrecognized response `S -> dirswitch (., /cvsrepo/)' 
from cvs server cvs checkout: warning: unrecognized response `S -> my_module (.,    
Updating, NULL, NULL)' from cvs server cvs checkout: warning: unrecognized response  
`S -> serve_directory (.)' 
from cvs server
cvs checkout: warning: unrecognized response `S -> dirswitch (., /cvsrepo/)' from cvs     
server cvs checkout: warning: unrecognized response `S -> do_cvs_command (checkout)'     from cvs server cvs checkout: warning: unrecognized response `S ->     server_notify()' from cvs server cvs [checkout aborted]: could not get working directory: Function not implemented S -> safe_location( where=(null) ) S -> Lock_Cleanup() S -> Simple_Lock_Cleanup() S -> server_cleanup()
-> close_connection_to_server ()
```

Let me know what other information is needed.  I feel like this is just some small permissioning problem that has been left out.

Comment: This question would suit more on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

cvs -t -d :pserver:pcm@localhost:/cvsrepo checkout .
instead of . checkout a module name
try CVSROOT

```
cvs -t -d :pserver:pcm@localhost:/cvsrepo checkout CVSROOT
```

should go to your local directory